# How to extract part of string from df, based on character vector in R

Tags: r, loops

I'd like to extract numbers from a string variable in a df, based on character vector.

```
# sample data
numbers <- as.character(seq(1000, 9900, 100))
df <- tibble(numbers)%>%
rename(string = 1)%>%
mutate(string = paste("some text", string, "another text"))
```

In real data, string in each row has a different length. My goal is to create a new variable, that contains numbers extracted from the "string" variable. I'm pretty new to R. Usually I would do something like this.

```
df2 <- df %>%
mutate(number = case_when(str_detect(string, "1000")==T ~ "1000",
                          str_detect(string, "1100")==T ~ "1100",
                          #don't want to type this 88 times more!
                          TRUE~string))
```

I thought about some kind of loop. I've tried this, but it didn't work.

```
for(i in numbers){
df2 <-  mutate(df, number = case_when(str_detect(string, i)==T ~ i,
                                      TRUE~string))
}
```

While I do understand, why my loop didn't achvied desired outcome, I can't figure out any other solution.
I would be grateful for help.

Comment: `df$number <-  gsub('\\D', '', df$string)` will remove all non-numerics from the string.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I was imprecise. Sometimes I have two numbers in a string. Lets say "a number between 200 and 500". You solution gives an outcome "200500".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this should be what you are looking for:

```
library(stringr)

df$num <- str_extract(df$string, '\\d\\d\\d\\d') # first pattern
df$num <- str_extract_all(df$string, '\\d\\d\\d\\d') # all patterns
```

Comment: Thanks. It extracs only four digits numbers. Is there a solution, that extracts all numbers (some thimes there are several) in a string, regardless of their length?

Comment: It is now in my answer